# vb.net regex parse paragraph from report

Tags: regex, string, vb.net

I have a report I am given in plain text that a coworker typically has to manually edit out various headers. I know the top line and bottom line of the header - they do not differ throughout the document, but the various lines of text between does.
Formatting looks like this:

```
BEGIN REPORT FOR CLIENT XXYYZZ
RANDOM BODY TEXT
RANDOM BODY TEXT
RANDOM BODY TEXT
RANDOM BODY TEXT
RANDOM BODY TEXT
FINAL REPORT
```

I am attempting to use regular expressions to highlight this text within a rich text box. If I use the below code I can highlight every occurrence of the top line without issue:

```
Dim mystring As String = "(BEGIN)(.+?)(XXYYZZ)"
Dim regHeader As New Regex(mystring)
Dim regMatch As Match = regHeader.Match(rtbMain.Text)

While regMatch.Success
    rtbMain.Select(regMatch.Index, regMatch.Length)
    rtbMain.SelectionColor = Color.Blue

    regMatch = regMatch.NextMatch()
End While
```

However, once I attempt to change the code to find the entire paragraph it no longer will highlight anything. Below is what I was expecting it to be but it does not seam to like it for whatever reason and will not highlight anything:

```
Dim mystring As String = "(BEGIN REPORT FOR CLIENT XXYYZZ)(.+?)(FINAL REPORT)"
Dim regHeader As New Regex(mystring)
Dim regMatch As Match = regHeader.Match(rtbMain.Text)

While regMatch.Success
    rtbMain.Select(regMatch.Index, regMatch.Length)
    rtbMain.SelectionColor = Color.Blue

    regMatch = regMatch.NextMatch()
End While
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [*singleline* mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), in order to let `.` match even newlines.

Try this:

```
Dim mystring As String = "(BEGIN REPORT FOR CLIENT XXYYZZ)(.+?)(FINAL REPORT)"
Dim regHeader As New Regex(mystring, RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim regMatch As Match = regHeader.Match(rtbMain.Text)

While regMatch.Success
    rtbMain.Select(regMatch.Index, regMatch.Length)
    rtbMain.SelectionColor = Color.Blue

    regMatch = regMatch.NextMatch()
End While
```

Notice `RegexOptions.Singleline`.